# Django- How can I allow only a set number of duplications with UniqueConstraint?

Tags: python, django, constraints

I'm making a webpage - a rental place that can rent movies, music cd's and books.
I've created a model of cd -

```
class Cd(models.Model):
cd_band=models.CharField(max_length=100)
cd_title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
CD_GENRE= (
    ('POP', "POP"),
    ("HIP", "Hip-Hop"),
    ("ROC", "Rock"),
    ("BLU", "Blues"),
    ("SOU", "Soul"),
    ("COU", "Country"),
    ("JAZ", "Jazz"),
    ("CLA", "Classical music"),
)
cd_genre=models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CD_GENRE)

cd_length=models.DurationField()

cd_rental=models.ForeignKey(Rental, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)


def __str__(self):
       # return self.cd_title, '\n', self.cd_band, '\n'
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.cd_band,self.cd_title,self.cd_genre)
```

But there is a rule that I have to apply here:

-One band can offer cd's in up to 2 genres. So let's say I create a cd of Band1 - Band1 can have cd's in only 2 genres - f.e rock and blues. I have no idea how to implement that.
I'm thinking about making a constraint, but I don't know what condition to implement:

```
UniqueConstraint.condition(fields=['cd_band','cd_genre'],condition=??????, name='unique_cd')
```

I've also thought of restructurizing my entire database - making a separate classes for bands and music genres, and then linking it with foreign keys, setting up validators. I think it should work, but I'd have to put in so much work.
Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the database structured this way, which is IMO not great for manipulation and future features. I'd put the check into `save()` method. Something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    bands_genres = set(Cd.objects.filter(cd_band=self.cd_band).values_list("cd_genre", flat=True))
    bands_genres.add(self.cd_genre)
    if len(bands_genres) > 2:
        raise SomeException
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

*Edit: Forgot to add that usually you want to use `.distinct()` after `values_list()`, but as I chose to use `set()` for this solution. It is not needed and has the same effect as `distinct()`.